# fold/reduce with complex accumulator

Tags: kotlin, fold

I have a list that looks like this:

```
val myList = listOf(
    Message(
      id= 1,
      info = listOf(1, 2)
    ),
    Message(
      id= 1,
      info = listOf(3, 4)
    ),
    Message(
      id= 2,
      info = listOf(5, 6)
    ) 
)
```

How can I convert it so the elements with the same id are combined?

```
listOf(
    Message
      id= 1
      info = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
    ),
    Message
      id= 2
      info = listOf(5, 6)
    ) 
)
```

I've tried the following, and it works

```
myList
    .groupBy { it.id }   
    .map { entry ->
        val infos = entry.value.fold(listOf<Int>()) { acc, e -> acc + e.info }

        Message(
            id = entry.key,
            info = infos
        )
    }
```

But I was wondering if there was an easier/cleaner/more idiomatic way to merge these objects. It seems like I would be able to do this with a single fold, but I can't wrap my brain around it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would also go for [`groupingBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html) but do it a bit differently via `fold` (compare also [`Grouping`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-grouping/)):

```
myList.groupingBy { it.id }
      .fold({ _, _ -> mutableListOf<Int>() }) { _, acc, el ->
        acc.also { it += el.info }
      }
      .map { (id, infos) -> Message(id, infos) }
```

This way you have only 1 intermediate map and only 1 intermediate list per key, which accumulates your values. At the end you transform it in the form you require (e.g. into a `Message`). Maybe you do not even need that? Maybe the map is already what you are after?

In that case you may want to use something as follows (i.e. narrowing the mutable list type of the values):

```
val groupedMessages : Map<Int, List<Int>> = myList.groupingBy { it.id }
    .fold({ _, _ -> mutableListOf() }) { _, acc, el ->
      acc.also { it += el.info }
    }
```

Comment: Hi this code returns something like this:

[Message(id=1, info=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), Message(id=2, info=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])]

Comment: @SomaiahKumbera I think the other overload of `fold` should be used: `.fold({ _, _ -> mutableListOf<Int>() }) { _, acc, el ->`.

Comment: you are both right... corrected it. Thanks for noting... should have tested it... :-)

Comment: Accepted. Few objects because of the mutableList. My final solution was this:


myList.groupingBy { it.id }
        .fold({ _, _ -> mutableListOf<Int>() }) { _, acc, el ->
            acc.also { it += el.info }
        }
        .map { (id, infos) -> Message(id, infos) }

Answer (score 1):

You can [`groupingBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html) the ids, then [`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html), which would perform a reduction on each of the groups.

```
myList.groupingBy { it.id }.reduce { id, acc, msg -> 
    Message(id, acc.info + msg.info) 
}.values
```

This will of course create lots of `Message` and `List` objects, but that's the way it is, since both are immutable. But there is also a chance that this doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things.

If you had a `MutableMessage` like this:

```
data class MutableMessage(
    val id: Int,
    val info: MutableList<Int>
)
```

You could do:

```
myList.groupingBy { it.id }.reduce { _, acc, msg ->
    acc.also { it.info.addAll(msg.info) }
}.values
```

Comment: Nice and succinct. Your answer really helped me understand reduce, and for that I am grateful. Thank you.

Comment: I ended up accepting Roland's answer because it created fewer objects. Thank you for your help Sweeper <3

Answer (score 0):

A solution without using reduce or fold:

```
data class Message(val id: Int, val info: List<Int>)

val list = listOf(
  Message(id = 1, info = listOf(1, 2)),
  Message(id = 1, info = listOf(3, 4)),
  Message(id = 2, info = listOf(5, 6))
)

val result = list
  .groupBy { message -> message.id }
  .map { (_, message) -> message.first().copy(info = message.map { it.info }.flatten() ) }

result.forEach(::println)
```

Answer (score 0):

By extracting out a few functions **which have a meaning of their own**, You can make it readable to a great extent.

```
data class Message(val id: Int, val info: List<Int>) {
    fun merge(that: Message): Message = this.copy(info = this.info + that.info)
}

fun List<Message>.mergeAll() =
    this.reduce { first, second -> first.merge(second) }

fun main() {
    val myList = listOf(
        Message(
            id = 1,
            info = listOf(1, 2)
        ),
        Message(
            id = 1,
            info = listOf(3, 4)
        ),
        Message(
            id = 2,
            info = listOf(5, 6)
        )
    )

    val output = myList
        .groupBy { it.id }
        .values
        .map { it.mergeAll() }

    println(output)
}
```